# SharePoint Online [Me] view filter not working

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list in SharePoint Online that I want to filter by the logged in user. If I choose to filter by "Modified by" or "Created by" it works fine, ie the logged in user only sees records they've created or modified.

If I choose to filter on a "Person or Group" custom column using is equal to [Me] it produces no records. Is there something else that needs to make this work for a "Person or Group" column?

Thanks

Screen images of the new list:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue with attempting to filter a custom column by [Me] in SharePoint online. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

As per my test, it works after I set the view shows only when Person or Group column is equal to [Me]. No anything else is needed.
[image]
Have a try in other lists, will this issue still exist?

Comment: Yes - happens for any list - existing or new. We also have an on-prem 2010 instance and [Me] works fine for a person/group column. Only an issue with our O365 SP Online instance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your person column setup to have multiple persons? Then set

- the column to single entry only
  or
- set the filter to `contains`

Also the `[Me]` option must be written in the language you are using in SharePoint. For example my SharePoint settings are german, so I have to write `[Ich]`.

Same goes for calculated columns where the commands are the english ones but the formatting/separation is in your local settings (in german it's `;` instead of `,` to separate values in formulas).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I still have the issue. Language is english, so the filter is written as [Me]. I created a brand new list with only the person column added and it still doesn't work. If I try to use contains, I get an error: "The filter type you selected cannot be used with this type of column. You can apply the 'contains' operator only to columns that have the type Single line of text..." This makes sense as the column type is person or group.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the same initially, that the `[Me]` filter was broke.  I only later discovered that the issue was we had not mapped the users during our migration.  So even though certain records were associated with my name it was a relic of my account from the on-prem site.  In reality they were not associated with my new identity in SPO.

Then when I updated a doc the new identity kicked in and the filter began to work on the newly modified items.